# Rest API services in azure

Tags: azure, http-post, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, rest

I am new to REST API services.
We got a requirement to extract the data from one of the on-premise environment. On-Premise team told us that they are sending HTTP Messages using POST method to URI.

On-Premise team asking us to share the URI in azure which accepts the HTTP Post Messages.

We are using Azure Data Factory where we can configure HTTP Data set and linked service but we cannot give any URI to on-premise team, in reverse ADF need HTTPS URI to extract the data. so this option is rolled out for us

Please let us know if blob can accept https post messages from on-premise if so how we can get the URI to share with on-premise team.

Is there any other way to implement this in azure ?

Regards,
Srinivas

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following link with specs about how to interact with Storage Account using REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob

PS: in the left menu, you'll find the related API spec for each service